# Click event of ToolBar menu is not working

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I am having Cart Icon in ToolBar. When I click the cart icon,I wrote code to navigate to the next activity.But the clicking is not working. Here is my code.Please help me to fix it.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();           /*-------Cart Basket with Counter---------*/
    mCounter = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    CommonUtil.dbUtil.open();
    MainFragmentAdapter.CART_COUNT = String.valueOf(CommonUtil.dbUtil.getCartItem().getCount());
    MainActivity.mCounter.setText(MainFragmentAdapter.CART_COUNT);

    invalidateOptionsMenu();

    badgeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Config.menuItemClicked = true;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = CommonUtil.pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("cart_Clicked", Config.menuItemClicked);
            editor.apply();
            Intent next = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
            startActivity(next);
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Did you make the layout clickable?

Comment: Use MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.badge)) to get the action view. It returns a view.

Comment: Yes I made the layout clickable @FrederickEskens

Comment: Sorry I could not get yo .. Can you edit my code that you suggest.? @MalithLakshan

Comment: @ParamaSudha Wrote an answer including the suggestion I made in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to ;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

   badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.badge).getActionView();           /*-------Cart Basket with Counter---------*/
   //instead of the above code try
   View badgeLayoutView=MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.badge));
   mCounter = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);

   CommonUtil.dbUtil.open();
   MainFragmentAdapter.CART_COUNT =String.valueOf(CommonUtil.dbUtil.getCartItem().getCount());
   MainActivity.mCounter.setText(MainFragmentAdapter.CART_COUNT);

   invalidateOptionsMenu();

   //set the onClick listener to badgeLayoutView
   badgeLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Config.menuItemClicked = true;
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = CommonUtil.pref.edit();
           editor.putBoolean("cart_Clicked", Config.menuItemClicked);
           editor.apply();
           Intent next = new Intent(context, ProductActivity.class);
           startActivity(next);
       }
   });
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

And make sure you're setting the action view poroperly in your menu XML file. You've to use the `app:actionLayout`

```
<item
    android:title="Badge"
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/your_action_layout"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //...
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please check if you are using scrollbar below toolbar..
>
> if you are using ScrollView that will make full screen scrollable
>
> use below line

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

inside ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

> try this

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the layout is clickable by defining `android:clickable="true"` in its XML.